# Android security issues

Tags: java, android, security

I recently found that the databases of Android apps are totally exposed. That said, my configuration is exposed, I save there passwords.

So, now my doubt resumes on java code.

```
String value = "example";
```

This could be an example where I store a password to pass by reference to webservice.

People, with some kind of software (like this example [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file)) could be able to get all the code? (I tried to follow the steps without success)

I read about http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html, how do I know that it's already implemented in my project?

> When you create an Android project, a proguard.cfg file is
>   automatically generated in the root directory of the project.

I checked my root directory and I don't have that file.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Can you be more clear exactly what the question is? Are you asking if people can reverse engineer your app, how to use proguard, or how to prevent reverse engineering?

Comment: yes you can decompile an apk and get access to the source code (though not always reliable), proguard is there to obfuscate your code but its still possible to figure it out. You can always do some encryption of whatever you want before you save it then decrypt it again when you want to use it.

Comment: There is a simple rule.  If you care about it, don't put it on a phone.  Do the authentication on a server and don't store the password.  if you store it on the phone, it is **impossible** to make it secure.  There are steps you can take to make it harder to get but then it's just a question of "is the effort to break it worth the reward?"  If the answer is yes, then don't put it on the phone because someone will get it.  That's why I have remote wipe on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

Obfuscation does not guarantee that your code won't be de-compiled. people who get your apk will still be able to review the code (although the flow of the app will be significantly more difficult to understand). Function names, variables and class names are changed but the code is still viewable.

password and other sensitive information should be kept in Android's keychain , where it's protected. never save passwords in a configuration file (preferences file).

Answer (score 1):

You can look into encrypting your local database with [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/). Proguard obfuscates code but will not hide your passwords if you have them hardcoded anywhere, it is not a tool to be used for security[[reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658219/how-secure-is-proguard-against-reverse-engineering). Also all of your network traffic is vulnerable unless you use some sort of [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

As you describe your app now it is trivial to get the passwords in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use char[ ] instead of string data type for storing sensitive values like password. This will make it difficult to recover if someone takes memory dump as value is not present string literal pool if used char[] data type.